# How to access C preprocessor constants in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, c-preprocessor

If I define a constant in my **C** .h file:

```
#define constant 1
```

How do I access it in my assembly .s file?

Comment: That's a macro not a constant. Does the pre-processor operate on your asm files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use the GNU toolchain, gcc will by default run the preprocessor on files with the `.S` extension (uppercase 'S'). So you can use all cpp features in your assembly file.

There are some caveats:

- there might be differences in the way the assembler and the preprocessor tokenize the input.
- If you `#include` header files, they should only contain preprocessor directives, not C stuff like function prototypes.
- You shouldn't use `#` comments, as they would be interpreted by the preprocessor.

Example:

File definitions.h

```
#define REGPARM 1
```

File asm.S

```
#include "definitions.h"

.text
.globl relocate

    .align 16
    .type relocate,@function
relocate:
#if !REGPARM
    movl  4(%esp),%eax
#endif
    subl  %ecx,%ecx
    ...
```

Even if you don't use gcc, you might be able to use the same approach, as long as the syntax of your assembler is reasonably compatible with the C preprocessor (see caveats above). Most C compilers have an option to only preprocess the input file (e.g. `-E` in gcc) or you might have the preprocessor as a separate executable. You can probably include this preprocessing prior to assembly in your build tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless a specific development chain allows it. But in 20 years or so of embedded programming I never saw one.

Usually, the only way for assembly and C to communicate is the linker, i.e. labels defined in C/C++ are accessable from within assembly (and vice versa).

When I had to share definitions between C/C++ and asm, I usually did it with a custom code generator.

Since high-level data are rarely exchanged with assembly, a few defines and maybe some external references are usually enough, and thus the code generator is really easy to make.

You can use for instance perl or awk to parse a very simple list of common constants and produce a pair of files, one with #defines and the other with the equivalent EQU directives.