# It is gcc not as that is responsible for the preprocessor in an assembly file?

Tags: gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor, eclipse-cdt

I have found that `CDT` uses the corresponding backend tool such as `x86_64-w64-mingw32-as` to compile an assembly file by default on eclipse, which is configured on `C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC Assembler`.

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
src/%.o: ../src/%.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler'
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

src/%.o: ../src/%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler'
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

src/%.o: ../src/%.S
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC Assembler'
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-as  -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

Though [Options Controlling the Kind of Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) says

> file.s Assembler code.
>   file.S file.sx Assembler code that must be preprocessed.

I think here `preprocessed` referrs to c preprocessor. But, it must be `gcc file.S` rather than `as file.S`(uppercase 'S'), the latter will prompt an error like `Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is`('` when the file contains C preprocessor. Take the following example(.S):

```
#ifdef __x86_64__

#if defined(SYMBOL_UNDERSCORE)
#define GLOBL_SYMBOL(x) _##x
#else
#define GLOBL_SYMBOL(x) x
/* #error "============" */
#endif

.globl GLOBL_SYMBOL(foo)

#endif
```

## ==

Thus, it is gcc that is responsible for the preprocessor(one step of working procedures of gcc), right?
According to this thinking, the following(.S) will work...

```
/* https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Architectures */
/* #ifdef __LP64__ || _LP64 */
#if defined(__i386__) || defined(_M_IX86)
# include "nomakefile/foo_x86.S"
#elif defined(__x86_64__) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_AMD64)
# include "nomakefile/foo_x64.S"
#else
# error Unsupported architecture
#endif
```

## Aslo

- [How do I enable the preprocessor in gcc assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993384/how-do-i-enable-the-preprocessor-in-gcc-assembly)
- [How to access C preprocessor constants in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276255/how-to-access-c-preprocessor-constants-in-assembly)

Comment: If you were trying to write a self-answered Q&A, make sure the question is a proper question that doesn't contain too much answer.  Multiple answers should be possible, from other people.

Comment: It's fun to answer my own question so that I can't help but try it. As a result, it's marked with '-1'. Yes, it's unuseful and I know I was wrong~

Comment: My point has nothing to do with your answer being wrong.  The point was that a lot of the text you put in the question should have been in the answer.  A giant question with a hypothesis only has a yes / no answer.  A smaller question like "how does gcc decide what to run" can have a real answer.

Comment: In fact, I found the C preprocessor didn't work in my `.S` file, and then I just guessed it, now I get it from [Binutils (as bfd binutils gprof ld)](http://www.gnu.org/manual/manual.en.html#binutils) to [3.1 Preprocessing](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Preprocessing.html#Preprocessing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The `gcc` binary decides what programs to invoke. If it sees a file with the suffix `s`, it invokes `as`. If it sees a file with the suffix `S`, it invokes `cpp` then `as`. The assembler `as` itself doesn't know about the suffix convention and won't invoke the C preprocessor for you.